# Change the visibility of an element based on state change in react JS

Tags: reactjs

In my code based on the ajax call am changing the state value. Based on thi it has to dispaly the flash message. In my code when state changes it is not displaying the flash message.

code:

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      email_error: "",
      password_error: "",
      showError: false,
      errorMessage: "Welcome",

    };

    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }
 login() {
    if (this.validateForm()) {
      PostData("loginWeb", this.state).then(result => {
        let responseJson = result;
        if (responseJson !== undefined && responseJson.success === true) {
          sessionStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify(responseJson));
          this.setState({ redirectToReferrer: true });
        } else if (
          responseJson !== undefined &&
          responseJson.success === false
        ) {
          this.setState({
            showError: true,
            errorMessage: responseJson.error
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({
            showError: true,
            errorMessage: "Invalid Credentials."
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
render(){
 return {
<div className="flaseMsg text-center">
          <FlashMassage persistOnHover={true}>
            {this.state.showError && (
              <div className="alert alert-danger alert-flashMsg">
                {this.state.errorMessage}
              </div>
            )}
          </FlashMassage>
        </div>
}

}
```

Please let me know what i have missed in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

first you code return method in you render method return {} it is not good change it to return this :

```
render(){
 return (  
  <div className="flaseMsg text-center">
      <FlashMassage persistOnHover={true}>
        {this.state.showError && (
          <div className="alert alert-danger alert-flashMsg">
            {this.state.errorMessage}
          </div>
        )}
      </FlashMassage>
    </div>
)
}
```

Comment: Actually am using this only but at the time of placing some part of code it missed. But this is not solving my issue.